# Showing singularity when eigenvalue $\lambda = 1$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Lets say I have matrix $M$ with all its entries $\geq 0$. Then how can I show that given $M$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda = 1$, then $(I-M)$ is not invertible. So far my attempt considers the system $Mx=x$ where you find that $x = [1  1...1]^T$. However, I am not sure where to go from here to show whether $(I-M)$ is not invertible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $Mx = x \iff Mx = Ix \iff Mx-Ix = 0 \iff (M-I)x = 0$